# RLMResults:allObjects crash (iOS Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I have old project written on Objective-C. Need to do migration to Realm.

I created several objects/classes inheritance from `RLMObject`. When I do fetching objects only with one main object type (`ConnectionRealm`) - working fine, but if I do add (only add, not include, not use) to project two or more another classes (inheritance from `RLMObject`), like as `FloorRealm` class, APP crash on `[ConnectionRealm allObjects]` without any errors.

Also `ConnectionRealm` contains `RLMArray` of `FloorRealm`. App still crashing.
(Can`t solve and understand this few days.) Thanks.

Connection Model:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Realm/Realm.h>

#import "FloorRealm.h"

@interface ConnectionRealm : RLMObject

@property int connectionID;

@property NSString *name;

@property NSString *localIPAddress;
@property NSString *localPort;

@property NSString *remoteIPAddress;
@property NSString *remotePort;

@property NSString *userName;
@property NSString *password;

@property NSString *deviceID;

@property RLMArray <FloorRealm *> *floors;

- (instancetype)initWith:(NSString *)name
                 localIP:(NSString *)localIPAddress
               localPort:(NSString *)lPort
                remoteIP:(NSString *)remoteIPAddress
              remotePort:(NSString *)rPort
                userName:(NSString *)userName
                password:(NSString *)password
                deviceID:(NSString *)deviceID;
@end

#import "ConnectionRealm.h"

@implementation ConnectionRealm

- (instancetype)initWith:(NSString *)name
                 localIP:(NSString *)localIPAddress
               localPort:(NSString *)lPort
                remoteIP:(NSString *)remoteIPAddress
              remotePort:(NSString *)rPort
                userName:(NSString *)userName
                password:(NSString *)password
                deviceID:(NSString *)deviceID {

    if (self = [super init]) {

        self.connectionID = [self incrementID];

        self.name = name;

        self.localIPAddress = localIPAddress;
        self.localPort = lPort;

        self.remoteIPAddress = remoteIPAddress;
        self.remotePort = rPort;

        self.userName = userName;
        self.password = password;

        self.deviceID = deviceID;
    }

    return self;
}

+ (NSString *)primaryKey { return @"connectionID"; }

- (int)incrementID {

    RLMResults *objects = [ConnectionRealm allObjects];
    return self.connectionID = [[objects maxOfProperty:@"connectionID"] intValue] + 1;
}

@end
```

FloorModel:

```
#import <Realm/Realm.h>


@interface FloorRealm : RLMObject

@property int floorID;
@property NSInteger floorNumber;
@property NSString *floorName;

- (instancetype)initWith:(NSInteger)floorNumber floorName:(NSString *)name;

@end
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(FloorRealm)

#import "FloorRealm.h"

@implementation FloorRealm

- (instancetype)initWith:(NSInteger)floorNumber floorName:(NSString *)name {

    if (self = [super init]) {

        self.floorID = [self incrementID];

        self.floorNumber = floorNumber;
        self.floorName = name;
    }

    return self;
}

+ (NSString *)primaryKey { return @"floorID"; }

- (int)incrementID {

    RLMResults *objects = [FloorRealm allObjects];
    return self.floorID = [[objects maxOfProperty:@"floorID"] intValue] + 1;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLVED]

1. `RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(FloorRealm)` need put on ConnectionRealm in .h after #includes. But in official docs written another.
2. Also: @property `RLMArray <FloorRealm *><FloorRealm> *floors;` instead of `@property RLMArray <FloorRealm *> *floors;`

I created test project with the same models and seed all errors. Strange, but in original project Xcode not showing this errors.